# Find a 10 digit number that contains all digits from 0 to 9 once, starts with a 3, and is also divisible by all whole numbers from 2 to 18

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Trial and error is always an option, but this question is from a timed math competition sheet, so it shouldn't take that long. Where do I start?

Edit: As far as the competition aspect is involved, a graphing calculator is allowed

Comment: First idea : The ending digit must be $0$ , and every such number is divisible by $9$ and therefore by $3$

Comment: The search isn't all that bad.  You know it has to be divisible by $16\times 9\times 5\times 7 \times 11\times 13\times 17=12252240$ and since it lies between $3\times 10^9$ and $4\times 10^9$ you get that the quotient must be between $245$ and $326$.  I don't immediately see how to narrow that down without actually checking the numbers.  But it takes less than a minute with a simple calculator.

Comment: @lulu But not with a table calculator :) I do not think that computers are allowed to be used. Otherwise , we could as well just apply brute force.

Comment: But you are not wrong after all. We can make the multiplications and look for duplicate digits, will take not too long ...

Comment: @Peter  I was a assuming that a simple hand calculator was allowed.  If I'm wrong about that...well, it's at least inconvenient even to compute that $12252240$ by hand.  And I don't see how to narrow my search range down with out some tedious work.

Comment: @lulu Ah, I think, I know understand your comment . You mean that this single number can be computed in under a minute, I assumed you mean checking all the numbers :)

Comment: If however, the calculator has a constant function (allowing repeated addition which some modern calculators seem not to have) , then the solution will take only some minutes when your hint is used. And with some luck, even faster.

Comment: @Peter  much less than a minute.  I happened to start at the upper end for some reason and found the answer in about 10 seconds.  That's good luck of course, but even starting at the lower end, the process is very fast.

Comment: @lulu How did you arrive at $309$ in about ten seconds (which is the solution) ?

Comment: @Peter I started at $326\times N$ ($N$ being the big product I mentioned) and subtracted $N$ repeatedly.  In truth, I did it on a spreadsheet, so I could check big blocks at a time.  I guess it does take a bit longer if you have to individually subtract $N$ each time.  Still, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number starts with $3$ and must end in $0$ as it is divisible by $10$. So we have
$$N=3abcdefgh0$$
As $N$ is divisible by $4$ we know that
$$10h+0\equiv0 \mod{4}$$
$$2h\equiv0 \mod{4}$$
$$\therefore h=6$$
As $N$ is divisible by $8$ we know that
$$100g+10(6)+0\equiv0 \mod{8}$$
$$4g\equiv4 \mod{8}$$
$$\therefore g=1$$
So we have
$$N=3abcdef160$$
As $N$ is divisible by $11$ we have that
$$-3+a-b+c-d+e-f+1-6+0\equiv0 \mod{11}$$
$$a-b+c-d+e-f\equiv8 \mod{11}$$
We also know that the remaining numbers are $\{2,4,5,7,8,9\}$, so the maximum value that this alternating sum can take is $13=7+8+9-2-4-5$ and the minimum  value is $-13=2+4+5-7-8-9$. As there are three even and three odd numbers remaining, their alternating sum must be odd so we must have that
$$a-b+c-d+e-f=-3$$
A quick study of the remaining digits gives that
$$7-8+5-9+4-2=-3$$
So
$$N=3785942160$$

Comment: Why  couldn't $h$ be $4$ or $8$?

Comment: $h$ could be $2,4,8$.  If $h$ is $2$ or $6$ then $g$ is odd, while if $h$ is $4$ or $8$ $g$ has to be even as well because of $8$.